# How to disable SSL 2.0 on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, https

Currently the app I'm working on uses NSURLConnection to connect to the server using HTTPS. The requirement is to enforce the prevention of connections using SSL 2.0 and to use only SSL 3.0 or TLS for connections. 
What should be done to disable SSL 2.0 support in the app? As far as i see lower level CFNetwork or Secure Transport API provide some control over SSL protocol, but should all the current NSURL* networking code be changed in order to do this?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you cannot achieve this with NSURLConnection.

However, `NSURLSession` provides APIs to configure a session via a `NSULRSessionConfiguration` and `TLSMaximumSupportedProtocol` and `TLSMinimumSupportedProtocol`.

Switching from `NSURLConnection` to `NSULRSession`/`NSURLSessionTask` should be straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I can't use NSURLSession because the app currently needs to support iOS 6.0. Will consider this option for the future though.